# Two versions of same line in "git diff"

Tags: git, git-diff

I've encountered strange behavior after switching branches. I've executed `git checkout master`, and I immediately had one file marked as modified. I ran `git reset --hard` to get rid of it, but to no effect. `git diff` gave me output like this:

```
diff --git a/Project/MYClass.cs b/Project/MYClass.cs
index 4f8405e..cb8ca4c 100644
--- a/Project/MYClass.cs
+++ b/Project/MYClass.cs
@@ -170,7 +170,7 @@ namespace Project
-            Logger.Warn(message);
+            Logger.Info(message);
```

But when I manually change it back, I get:

```
diff --git a/Project/MyClass.cs b/Project/MyClass.cs
index cb8ca4c..4f8405e 100644
--- a/Project/MyClass.cs
+++ b/Project/MyClass.cs
@@ -170,7 +170,7 @@ namespace Project
-            Logger.Info(message);
+            Logger.Warn(message);
```

So git can't decide which one was it. To make it funnier, if I change it to something completely different, I get:

```
diff --git a/Project/MYClass.cs b/Project/MYClass.cs
index 4f8405e..cb8ca4c 100644
--- a/Project/MYClass.cs
+++ b/Project/MYClass.cs
@@ -170,7 +170,7 @@ namespace Project
-            Logger.Warn(message);
+            Logger.Error(message);
diff --git a/Project/MyClass.cs b/Project/MyClass.cs
index cb8ca4c..4f8405e 100644
--- a/Project/MyClass.cs
+++ b/Project/MyClass.cs
@@ -170,7 +170,7 @@ namespace Project
-            Logger.Info(message);
+            Logger.Error(message);
```

When I ran `git ls-tree -r master | Select-String "myclass.cs"` I got this:

```
100644 blob 4f8405e28faa09981a3f76775b1693db31b0bdad    Project/MYClass.cs
100644 blob cb8ca4c60f10f959422ecc2cbdb91d0e693ea380    Project/MyClass.cs
```

I see and understand something is off, but I have no idea how did it happen.

I know how to fix it brutal way, removing my local and fetching everything from remote, but I want to know what causes it, and how to fix it properly.

Comment: Are you by any chance working on windows? What's the output of this? Could you add it to the question? `git ls-tree -r master | grep -i class.cs`.

Comment: Was it possible that some settings from your editor cause files (settings) to be changed automatically?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, I'm currently on Windows. I've added the output to the question, it seems quite strange.

Comment: @Christoph I thought that might be the case, so I quit my IDE and edited it in vim, still nothing.

Comment: Just try to get a reproducible example. Start to delete stuff until the error is gone. Is this your only project where this happens?

Comment: Hmm... I would bet the problem is the casings of the filenames. Probably they have different casings and then windows (and git, as we can see over here) is getting tricked with it. I'd like to make sure of it. Run this command now and past the output there: `git cat-file -p $( git cat-file -p master | grep tree | sed 's/.* //' )`

Comment: Depending on the output, we might ask for another command to be run (most likely)

Comment: @eftshift0 I've ran it (semi-manually though, lack of `sed` in PowerShell hurts), got `040000 tree 38aa751bbf2d46facb2dfd123b7e9671451135f9    Project` so I ran it again to get to this file, and I got exactly same output as one from `git ls-tree -r master`, so this file, listed twice with different hashes. But, there is no other file in this directory, so I have no idea what is it being tricked with.

Comment: Oh, my bad, indeed there is difference in casing, lost it when I was changing name to this generic `Class.cs`, I'll edit post to reflect it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git believes you have two different files in the `Project` directory / folder:

- `MYClass.cs` (uppercase `M`, uppercase `Y`, uppercase `C`, lowercase `lass.cs`)
- `MyClass.cs` (uppercase `M`, lowercase `y`, uppercase `C`, lowercase `lass.cs`)

Git opens each file name separately, writes out the contents for that file, and closes it.

Since you are on Windows, which refuses to make two different files whose names differ only in *case*, your OS *overwrites* one of the two files with the other one, leaving only one of the two casings in place.  Your OS won't let Git have two files in the work-tree.  Git *can* (and does) have both files in the *index*, because Git's index is actually a data file, not a directory / folder.  Since Git makes its commits out of the index, Git can make new commits that continue to contain two different files whose name differs only in case.

You must update your index so that it contains only *one* such name, otherwise you're doomed on Windows (and MacOS) to forever fight this problem.  The easy way is to do the fixing on a Linux or Unix system, where the index and work-tree stay in sync since the OS can and does create two different files whose name differs only in case.

The hard way is to use `git rm --cached`: give it the one name you really want gone.  Git will remove that file from the index, without affecting the work-tree at all.  Now that the index has the correct case, you can fix the case in the work-tree to match, however one does this on Windows—on other systems, the usual trick is:

```
mv NameWithCASEISSUE x   # change the whole name a lot, using a safe name
mv x NameWithCaseIssue   # change it back, using the correct case this time
```

Now you can compare the index version with the work-tree version and make any adjustments that might be required.  Since there's only one index version that will match the work-tree file, regardless of case issues (of which there aren't any now, because you have carefully made the filename cases match), you can get your job done.

The really unfortunate case (if I can use that word :-) ) occurs when you really *do* want both file names, differing only in case, in the index and in future commits.  There are no good tools for dealing with this.  It's theoretically possible to build such tools around the `git update-index` and `git checkout-index` commands, but they do not exist at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Torek! Why do you steal my answer? :-P

As Torek is explaining (with much greater detail than I would), the problem is that you have two different files for git.... but when git uses Windows FS API, they are both hitting the same file on the FS..... and that explains the whole problem. How do you solve it? If you don't mind fixing the problem moving forward, keep the real file you want with the content you want and delete the other with `git rm` and commit. If you want to fix it going back in time, then see where the second file showed up, amend that revision by removing it and rewrite the history on top of it.